# Why can't I reach the names from the DB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

//user.js

I created the following model Schema with mongoose:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    ThisSetup: [{name: String, quote: String}]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

In the mongoDB I can see in the terminal, that this concept is working fine, but if I try to display name property with ejs the following way, ids are displayed, but the names not:

//userid.ejs

```
<% User.forEach(function(User){ %>
    <div class="row">
        <p><%= User._id %>   <%= User.ThisSetup.name%></p>
    </div>
<% }); %
```

This way I see in the browser the names and the quotes too:

```
<%= User.ThisSetup %>
```

How can I reach just the names?

Thank you for in advance

Comment: Try this - `<% User.ThisSetup.forEach(function(User){ %>
    <div class="row">
        <p><%= User._id %>   <%= User.name%></p>
    </div>
<% }); %`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I tried, but it doesn't work that way either

Comment: `ThisSetup` is defined as an array, so you need to specify which element you want the name of.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

The solution:

```
<%= User.thisSetup[0].name %>
```